# Angular2 RC1 - Which event is fired whenever a component is called?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a Products component, and visiting beow url displays products list:

```
/products
```

The products page has pagination in it so users can click Next/Previous links shown at the end of the page. Clicking Next on first page moves user to below url:

```
/products/2
```

In my component I have implemented ngOnInit which fetches the products list, on the basis of the page which we currently on.

In Beta versions I was using CanReuse hook to make it work. But in current version when I click Next page, since ngOnInit isn't called on page 2, it doesnt fetch the products list.

I read somewhere that CanReuse will be added in future updates, I was wondering is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: I was checked the documentation, and the evens that angular2 have are these:

    `OnInit = 0,
    OnDestroy = 1,
    DoCheck = 2,
    OnChanges = 3,
    AfterContentInit = 4,
    AfterContentChecked = 5,
    AfterViewInit = 6,
    AfterViewChecked = 7,`

Maybe one can help you.

Comment: Thank you Koronos for your reply. But which one of them is fired when we visit i.e. products/2 from products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `Router` and use it's `changes` `EventEmitter` in your Component on which you can subscribe.

You could then use `location.path()` to read the current path for example with a `switch case`. Something like this:

```
...
constructor(private _location:Location, private _router:Router) {
    _router.changes.subscribe( () => {
        switch(this._location.path()){
            case '/products':
                 // do some stuff...
                 break;
            case '/products/2':
                // do something different...
                break;
            default:
                // do nothing..
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: My English es pretty bad.

I do some test and the event that is trigger when you enter for second time o thirth is `AfterViewInit`

You can implement it like this:

```
import {Component,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import {DataTableComponent} from '../../../shared/data-table/datatable.component.ts';

@Component({
    template: require('./consultorios-list.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./consultorios-list.component.scss')],
    directives: [DataTableComponent]
})

export class ConsultoriosListComponent implements OnInit {
    private datos:any = {
        titles: null, data: null
    };

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('I was printed when you enter to this route is showed c:');
    }
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Enjoy my friend.

Comment: Thank you Koronos for your efforts, unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Can you please add Next Page a link to your template. For example in my case I have <a [routerLink]="['/products/2']">Next Page</a>  and see if it works. In my case neither ngOnInit nor ngAfterViewInit is called when I visit Next Page i.e. /products/2

Comment: Can you make a example in plunker of how is your structure?